# MySQL incorrect search record returned

Tags: mysql

I have an issue with the way MySQL is searching for text in columns. I have a text string to search for but the DB is returning different variations of the string, specifically ignoring the hyphen in the column data. an example:

Search for **'%800fm%'** and its returning data with the string **'800F-M'** I only want to return data that matches the searched for string (i.e. in this situation don't ignore the hyphen in the column value)

I have tried the below queries but i still keep getting the records with hyphens:

```
SELECT p.partNo,
       p.stripedPartNo,
       p.ID AS partId,
       m.manufacturerName,
       concat(m.manufacturerName, ' ', p.partNo) AS fullPartName,
       1 AS `order`
FROM parts p
JOIN manufacturers m ON m.ID = p.manufacturerID
JOIN partSearchCache pc ON pc.partID = p.id
WHERE MATCH (pc.partName) AGAINST ('800FM')
  AND p.managerApproved = 1
LIMIT 100
```

and

```
    SELECT p.partNo,
           p.stripedPartNo,
           p.ID AS partId,
           m.manufacturerName,
           concat(m.manufacturerName, ' ', p.partNo) AS fullPartName,
           1 AS `order`
    FROM parts p
    JOIN manufacturers m ON m.ID = p.manufacturerID
    JOIN partSearchCache pc ON pc.partID = p.id
    WHERE MATCH (pc.partName) AGAINST ('%800FM%')
      AND p.managerApproved = 1
    LIMIT 100
```

and

```
SELECT p.partNo,
       p.stripedPartNo,
       p.ID AS partId,
       m.manufacturerName,
       concat(m.manufacturerName, ' ', p.partNo) AS fullPartName,
       1 AS `order`
FROM parts p
JOIN manufacturers m ON m.ID = p.manufacturerID
JOIN partSearchCache pc ON pc.partID = p.id
WHERE pc.partName LIKE '%800FM%'
  AND p.managerApproved = 1
LIMIT 100
```

I have enabled a **FULLTEXT** index ont he **pc.partName** column but still do not get the desired result.

I realise that the MATCH AGAINST wont work as i indent but I thoughts i'd show those examples to show what i am trying to achieve.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be useful if you could show us your backend. You should probably use LIKE BINARY. Binary uses bites comparison.

Usage:

```
SELECT * 
FROM people 
WHERE name LIKE BINARY '%abc%' ;
```

This will also force case-sensitivity, which is more accurate.

See link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

If it didn't help, show me your data, I might be able to rewrite a query that is more consistent.

Comment: I have marked this as correct as the original query worked and this worked. What i wasnet aware of though was that another developer had changed the way the pc.partName was populated - turns out this was changed to remove the hyphen.. changing the query to search p.partNo worked as expected. Score 1 for communication breakdown..